# Python: write .mov video file frame by frame

Tags: python

Is there a way to write a .mov file frame by frame with RGA images in Python? I am ingesting API data and don't know all the frames before-hand and don't want to write them as a batch once it's done receiving.

Comment: Title says GIF, question says MOV. Which is it?

Comment: Surely he wanted to say, in the title, `.mov`

Comment: thanks for highlighting my mistake. corrected the title